# How to move UITextField above keyboard to show text while typing in a UITextField inside a toolBar

Tags: ios, swift, keyboard, uitextfield, toolbar

I want to replicate the effect of iMessage structure, tapping on a UITextView in the toolBar, keyboard shows up. But I don't know how to display the text while I'm typing. I think I should move the `UITextField` up when keyboard appears

```
class ViewController: UIViewController, UITextFieldDelegate {

    @IBOutlet weak var myLabel: UILabel!
    @IBOutlet weak var myTextField: UITextField!



    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        myTextField.delegate = self

    }


    func textFieldShouldReturn(textField: UITextField) -> Bool {
        print("return pressed")
        self.myLabel.text = myTextField.text
        myTextField.resignFirstResponder()
        return true

    }


}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:
https://github.com/RobinChao/ChatMessageTableViewController

This is perfect for your intention.